# Can not delete Managed Solution for Dynamics 2015 (v7.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need help for a problem related to customization for Dynamics CRM 2015 (version 7.0.1.129). I can`t delete Managed Solution for Dynamics 2015 (v7.0)
But before that, I want to provide you technical data on how my system is shaped.

I have two available developer environments for Exporting Solutions for our clients.

- The First environment is for exporting Unmanaged and managed packages for 6.1. which works and for Dynamics 365 (v8.2)
- And the second environment where we do export just a managed v7.0.

The issue is only 7.0 related. The version exported from 6.1 works fine on 6 to 8.2 - excluding 7.0. Hence we need to do special export for 7.0 from 7.0 environment.

When we import Managed 7.0 on Dynamics CRM 2013 (7.0.1.129)(DB 7.0.1.129) and then try to delete the Solution we get an error that prevents to delete it.
The error is related to the Ribbon WorkBench. Note we do manually edit the export solution to add, display or hide our buttons from Dynamics and Outlook (and this works for v6-8 excluding 7)

I tried several options:

1. To downgrade to the previous working version of the Solution (excluding the ribbon changes)
2. change the XML file and try again. ( works if I delete all additional buttons and Display rules connected to them).
3. Enter into "Settings --> Customizations --> Customize the System --> Processes and Deactivate and Delete our processes.

Our only Option at the moment is to restore data from the backUp and continue with researching the problem.

The Error message says that the Ribbon component has more than 20 dependencies within the same solution

Here is a sample error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The RibbonCommand(account:concep.account.OpenSendAccounts) component cannot be deleted because it is referenced by 20 other components. F
or a list of referenced components, use the RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest.Detail:
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/.../Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147160033</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="schemas.datacontract.org/.../System.Collections.Generic">
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>0</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">RibbonCommand</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>1</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">account:concep.account.OpenSendAccounts</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>2</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">20</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>3</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">Solution</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>4</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">&lt;a id='a_helplink' tabindex='0' class='ms-crm-Dialog-Error-Link' onclick='openStdWin("\x2fDEV-CRM13\x2ftools\x2fdependency\x2fdependencyviewdialog.aspx\x3fobjectid\x3d\x257baff99d13-2b5e-4674-ada8-166897911fd5\x257d\x26objecttype\x3d7100\x26operationtype\x3ddependenciesforuninstall", null, 800, 600, null)'&gt;Details&lt;/a&gt;</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
</ErrorDetails>
<Message>The RibbonCommand(account:concep.account.OpenSendAccounts) component cannot be deleted because it is referenced by 20 other components. For a list of referenced components, use the RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest.</Message>
<Timestamp>2017-05-04T07:49:45.6747279Z</Timestamp>
<InnerFault i:nil="true" />
<TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: "Add Required Components" to the source environment should fix this (the solution seems to depend on something that's not a part of the solution itself, but is nonetheless there in the target environment). That, or the buggy solution mechanism is at it again...